# Is the teacher reading from an actual mythology story?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, mythology

In the Next Generation episode [Hero Worship](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hero_Worship_(episode)) there is a scene where a school teacher is reading mythology to the students. There is only [one line](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/211.htm) of the story read in the episode:

> TEACHER: Dara and her brother found themselves in the land of Tagas where the ruler, Elamos the Magnificent, had proclaimed as law. 'No children will be tolerated within the Great Kingdom'. When Dara saw the proclamation, she just laughed, and said, 'How magnificent a ruler, to be frightened by the likes of us.'

Is this a line from an existing mythological story or was it made up just for the episode?

Comment: Well, [the first sentence is used as a sample translation from Spanish to Hungarian...](http://glosbe.com/es/hu/tag) (3rd from the bottom)

Answer (score 8):

The Star Trek Encyclopedia [gives no indication that it exists outside of Star Trek](http://books.google.com/books?id=cbYf2l7gczUC&pg=PT612&lpg=PT612&dq=dara+tagas+elamos&source=bl&ots=lFlNE9i_Su&sig=gfNYStJPqaw4LEh2v4UfIs1RzGg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cG_EU6GsKsaKyAS4m4EI&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=dara%20tagas%20elamos&f=false):

[image: Elamos the Magnificent]

And aside from the amusing example sentence I posted as a comment, all my other search results are also from Star Trek sites.

Answer (score 5):

Within the context of the rest of the lesson and episode, I think it becomes clear that the story is probably not from Earth mythology.

The temple model the children are, and Timothy is later, building is the "Dokkaran temple of Kural Hanesh".

A google search for Elamos, Tagas and Dara seems to only bring up references to this episode.

[Transcript from Hero Worship](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/211.htm)